# Why does the thread sanitizer complain about acquire/release thread fences?

Tags: c++, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic, thread-sanitizer

I'm learning about different memory orders.

I have this code, which works and [passes GCC's and Clang's thread sanitizers](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIADMAKykAA6oCoRODB7evnppGY4CIWGRLDFxXLaY9kUMQgRMxAQ5Pn4BdpgOWQ1NBCUR0bEJyQqNza15VWN9A2UVEgCUtqhexMjsHObxocjeWADUJvFuTEQseKbx2CYaAILbu/uYRydOY8SYrMc3948Mey8h2ObgICE%2BTHQP1udwOcKO91CBAOMwIL2OABEDhpjlZ7mN0CAQGdUBdkAB9JEHJivLE4%2BJ4h73ABuqDw6AO/FQEEWCIeAHZGfDOSQDhAqXhadjcQdJSCDlx6RZZdZrIsYcKTIKNcL4QB3BB0F4QJgAOloqEhEAJRLYLBIAE9ySQsMRyUxkABHLx4T68sBgTHY3laqz8jE63Uoxpo1WWXGR3VmsYkTAQKrRwkgO2O53EV3kz70JhKdUMxNaiN/cMwmGs9kHKJNHl80OJ/jEMUSqVK2WvNwK3t4OMWdX3TXa8dRg4Go1is0Wq027OYe3EJ0u2Lur0%2Bv0HANBrgh7U1qdR1GYEcJs9J00pz4QDSkTO21e5zduotfUvX2Hwyu1qeTJ3FSLBMKEPKAcq/43suYIQhyXLkmC1CoKgZZCvCcHgl8HJNm6KH4RhFY3khYKmtobIMJB5Y3vhyEIBRVE0YylYcMstCcIkvB%2BBwWikKgnBuCOKKrOs6JmPEPCkAQmjscsADWCQAJymlwAAcXCJGYXBcAAbFIZiSGYyScRwkg8XJAmcLwCggE%2Bsl8expBwLAMCICgpIpEaZAUBAaAsN59BxMAulVDQtBosQdkQFEVlRKETQOpw0kBWwggAPIMLQyVOaQWBgUY4h5fgnzdMymB2XlmCqF0XholZSI1FZtB4FExBJR4WBWQQxB4CwKXOVQBjAAoABqeCYHqGUpIwg0yIIIhiOwUgLfIShqFZuhVAYRgoCO%2BhtXZkDLKgKR1FVAC0BKYqY8aWGYGgHJdADqYi0M9L01b1NKXbN6CGI4yCXbExAkAoz1UAohiZAAXpe8QYvBuHPcAtk1F0dQuAw7ieG0ejBKEgzlMMVQFJkAiTH4ZPpBTDBzEMlTVLUPTjC0eNTMzmOs7MRPzKTths1TegzM0DMk5UywKGJGx6L1mCbDwHFcZZeWCRwqjqXpl16ZIBzAMgyAKlwalisJ902AcuCEKK2wZh4gU%2BUcklHrwjlaIsywILhww8qQSmJE%2BZkWaQA2B6QvH8ertn2TJcnLK5HmrAQKT1eQlABUFAuYPgRBM/wi2iOIq0F%2BtKjqHl8uK7weodSkg3Kxw3ER1Z6sZfVqfIqgVAHJr2u6/rhvG6bEAO1nnZ24sbvx17PtxH7we8GHT6R7w0e2LH7vyf7CQm2Y/JJOpkj8iZ/L8sp%2B/6Jw8Sq1HNlx05CfuYnEBIJnPnp/5Xk%2BSgu2hfEGgnwRSijFOKeUErMHXPNNKjACBZRylZAqhhgDFX4qVbmFUqr8RqnVBqeUmpmX4q1dqnUMCbH4r1fqDc%2BAjXGpNaas1eLSVLktYu0hS6KHLltfw%2BhkH7QtodKIx0/ZnQupwa6BAoSIzulYB6T1XrvU%2Bt9Dqz1/qA0uCDYgYNoqQ2hgwOGCMkY4UhKjdGLNnAQFcMLKohNSiM3yLTOo1jUiOKyOLBY0wMbdAEL0CYHNqZc28fUNm7iBai3ZrkAJ4TQmSxWGsWWVQq7ULMs3Ve1kNZax1nrPYyCFTxFNBoApZsDpW1zrbF2z4x5O22GYKeD8Paz0hL7RS/hVJ6UkgZZSyl1KJHaZIDQGkr7mSXiAcOaT152QcvHFyz8kDJ07p/d%2BwUeE5xtvnWQrCVrsNkJwzaldPjV1ILXJg9duDORSbfNenB24p3qgcbuvdMkDxyUYPJBSimj2/sFZ28RanT0fo010lBG4h2Xi3NW99Jn1O3kpMwqlEiSEkOpZSkhdL72UrrZSplr6XPSf8hpQyzC4vXlvT2pAKrRSyCASQQA):

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
    
int state = 0;
std::atomic_int a = 0;

void foo(int from, int to) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        while (a.load(std::memory_order_acquire) != from) {}
        state++;
        a.store(to, std::memory_order_release);
    }
}

int main()
{    
    auto x = std::async(std::launch::async, foo, 0, 1);
    auto y = std::async(std::launch::async, foo, 1, 0);
}
```

I reckon that an 'acquire' load is unnecessary if it doesn't end up returning `from`, so I decided to use a 'relaxed' load, followed by an 'acquire' fence.

I expected it to work, but it's [rejected by the thread sanitizers](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEgOykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBLSAA6oCoRODB7evgGkyamOAqHhUSyx8VK2mPYFDEIETMQEmT5%2BXIF2mA7pdQ0ERZExcQm29Y3N2W0jvf0lZQkAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMxhyN5YANQmm25MRCx4ppvYJhoAgls7e5iHx04KBMSYrEfXdw8Muy8ByObioXgIK0wPxut32cMOdzCBH271OzyOABF9hojlY7u90CAQKdUOdkAB9JH7JgvLE4zZ4%2B53ABuqDw6H2/FQECpVGIpNI%2BypRHmCPu/kZ8M5JH2PMEQtp2NxCpB%2By49IsQus1nmMKlJgleql8IA7gg6M8IEwAHS0VBMdAQAlEtgsEgAT3JJCwxHJnwMqkw6FFYDAmM5/JYooNVn8GKNxpRBEJxLOF3JBAQnwd5KojDWTuTLswbuInu9cXJTGQAEcvHhPrqGQnjaiCFDLNrm3dE3Cbe8SJgIERBc6QK6PV7iD6/VUvkom5L4Qb4384zCYVSWEwwhBdWvNcue/CmODUPtVIqx0wFO6AYWUwYvACkMTbwDBVzBRpBVxFy3TyIfZ3SvIs3zvZAHyJJ8XyJG8IM/VBUF/b9/zXDEOEWWhOAAVl4PwOC0UhUE4NxtUsFFllWdEzE2HhSAITRMMWABrEBNgATmtHCuA4/wADYcI4zYzDMfwzEkDR%2BP0ThJHwpjiM4XgFBAH9GMIzDSDgWAYEQFBSUSC0yAoCA0BYQz6HiYAuBsvg6HbYgVIgaIFOiMIGndTh6LMthBAAeQYWhPI00gsG3IxxBC/BPi6ZlMBUkLMEDZBwXWIikSqBTaDwaJiA8jwsAUj48BYLzNKoAxgAUAA1PBMBNPzEkYMqZEEEQxHYCp%2BEERQVHUELdC4fRDGMcibGy6IVMgRZUESGoEoAWgJTFTE7SwzA0fYFoAdTEWgtu2pKPhpBamvQQxHGQBa4n5RytqoBRDDSAAvKFNgxTNsw5BbgGUucumcCBXHGVoggYdAZkGcpchSNIBBBvQ8jhhhIdKIYho6AHalGJpPBaPRMZqHpGlRuYMZxhHyemMIBjR8pFgUKi1j0D5MHWHgsNw%2BSQpIjhVAADn4hb%2BMkfZgGQZA1S4a0uFlMi1psfZcEIGUtiG/YPHMozDlov9eHUrR5kWBAvh9ShWJAHCf2wjg5NIUqrdIAiiN55TVIYpjFm0vTlgIRJwXISgzIs9GgnwIhoe64RRHELrZF6tQis%2BdneBNPLEjKzmODwp2FN5vzwX95FUCoC9BeF0XxclmyZblgztbV%2BZ9c943TaGPcZNt3gHZ/Z3eFd2x3YN5jSDYzYNGtYScM2TiOJwyRhJsrhNk7zZuZdpSPY0r3dO9iAkGDozA9M%2BvLJQAwjGXjQfxoWgHKclyQrc5gyxanzGAIAKgoUsKRsiojoqdEcHFBKREkqdFSgpDKNsiITTymWAqaV9bEBKpnPglUap1Qak1Ai9Eo7tVjtIKOCd%2BpEV0GYYaRgUBjX0DlKaHdZrzU4EtZMK0xobQOntA6R08pbTOhdC411iC3QUPdR6DAXpvQ%2BlmU2W1fqVGqOkFw4NKZgwhjTWYockY1FUdo9IpNQ6E26BTPGEwFFAOMdTYoUMCYmKyKDVEJMNE2L/EsFYzMhqsxTlnHOfdFJ83LiLfYuwRpqk2NaCem0IDyysJYQUysI46zooKTWIdiBJLME3LehtW4OnbhbMwXF%2BK0X4rxDi/McLFMklwfmnc7Y91zjzTeKk1Key0rvJAvsi7H0PmfChQYVaR1kAQzqRD45KETiFLxLU05MAztwTSNtfF504AXP24J9glzLkLIJISjBhIiREuuWtLIZKycPI2pATZ5PiB3G29TLa9xWRwN2rTt4FK4vPSQ/MOKSBsmJDiIs56r3Xv3TeFys5mFBf45u7zSBxUckoyQQA%3D%3D), which claim that concurrent `state++`s are a data race.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
    
int state = 0;
std::atomic_int a = 0;

void foo(int from, int to) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        while (a.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) != from) {}
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
        state++;
        a.store(to, std::memory_order_release);
    }
}

int main()
{    
    auto x = std::async(std::launch::async, foo, 0, 1);
    auto y = std::async(std::launch::async, foo, 1, 0);
}
```

Why is this a data race?

[Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence) says that

> **Atomic-fence synchronization**
>
> An atomic release operation X in thread A synchronizes-with an acquire
> fence F in thread B, if
>
> - there exists an atomic read Y (with any memory order)
> - Y reads the value written by X (or by the release sequence headed by X)
> - Y is sequenced-before F in thread B
>
> In this case, all non-atomic and relaxed atomic stores that are
> sequenced-before X in thread A will happen-before all non-atomic and
> relaxed atomic loads from the same locations made in thread B after F.

In my understanding, all conditions are met:

- "there exists an atomic read Y (with any memory order)" — check: `a.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)`.
- "Y reads the value written by X" — check, it reads the value from `a.store(to, std::memory_order_release);`.
- "Y is sequenced-before F in thread B" — check.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Does it actually mention that anywhere? Can't find it. :/

Comment: It vaguely says that it only handles pthread and atomic intrinsics, but indeed the documentation is severely lacking. Documentation on how to use `__tsan_acquire` would also have been nice, but it doesn't seem to be one of their priorities :-(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The thread sanitizer currently [doesn't support `std::atomic_thread_fence`](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97868). (GCC and Clang use the same thread sanitizer, so it applies to both.)

GCC 12 (currently trunk) warns about it:

```
atomic_base.h:133:26: warning: 'atomic_thread_fence' is not supported with '-fsanitize=thread' [-Wtsan]
  133 |   { __atomic_thread_fence(int(__m)); }
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

To stop the sanitizer from disregarding fences, you can manually instrument them, using `__tsan_acquire` and `__tsan_release`.

[`#include <sanitizer/tsan_interface.h>`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/compiler-rt/include/sanitizer/tsan_interface.h)

```
while (a.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) != from) {}
__tsan_acquire(&a); // <--
std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
```

I assume it's tricky to automatically determine which atomic variables are affected by the fence.

Even though the bug report says [`seq_cst` fences are not affected](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/1352#issuecomment-742438604), the code is still rejected if I use such a fence, they still need to be annotated with `__tsan_acquire`+`__tsan_release`, [exactly the same as acq-rel fences](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/1482#issuecomment-1004256509).