# How do I annotate seq-cst atomic fences for the thread sanitizer?

Tags: c++, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic, thread-sanitizer

I learned that [TSAN doesn't understand `std::atomic_thread_fence`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70542993/2752075), and to fix it, you need to tell TSAN which atomic variables are affected by the fence, by putting `__tsan_acquire(void *)` and `__tsan_release(void *)` next to it (for acquire and release fences respectively).

But what about seq-cst fences? As I understand, they're more strict than acq-rel fences, so acq-rel annotations might not be enough?

I'm not too familiar with different memory orders, so I might be missing something.

Comment: [Asked about it on github](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/1482).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dvyukov on Github [confirmed](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/1482#issuecomment-1004256509) the `__tsan_acquire`+`__tsan_release` instrumentation (same as for acq-rel fences) should be enough.

I'm not sure if it means that TSAN doesn't distinguish between seq-cst and acq-rel operations in general, or not.