Why do reference counts require both a release and acquire operation on the decrement?
Given a reference count decrement such as the following:
void release_and_maybe_deallocate(std::atomic<int>& count, foo* data)
{
    if (count.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel) == 1)
    {
        delete data;
    }
}

It's usually given as common knowledge that while the increment can use std::memory_order_relaxed (because the reference count must already be at least 1 because the reference count must've been acquired from somewhere else that was already holding a reference when it became visible to the current thread), while the decrement has to be both an acquire and a release operation. My question is why exactly the acquire part is necessary, at least during the decrement.
I would imagine that the above could also written as:
void release_and_maybe_deallocate(std::atomic<int>& count, foo* data)
{
    if (count.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release) == 1)
    {
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
        delete data;
    }
}

Which would save a fence on the "happy" path that someone else is still holding a reference. My first thought as to why this might not work was that potentially an acquire might be needed because the sub needs to synchronise with all the previous increments, but I don't think that's correct, because the increments are all relaxed, so there's no guarantee that any increments could be visible on the other thread. In other words, this series of events might happen:

Thread A creates a refcount with value 1
Thread A publishes a pointer to the refcount and makes it visible with value 1 to Thread B
Thread B does a relaxed increment on the refcount, which isn't made visible to Thread A
Thread A decrements the refcount, but because the increment above hasn't yet been released, it still appears as 1 after an acquire and therefore Thread A deallocates the memory
Thread B accesses the memory and causes a bug

So I would assume that the act of accessing the memory to decrement it is somehow sufficient to observe the relaxed increments on thread B, otherwise the above may happen and even acq_rel wouldn't be sufficient for decrementing the refcount.
EDIT: reconsidering the above, there's actually nothing preventing 4) happening before 3), so in order for the above to avoid UB in 5) Thread B would have to release a message to A, which would have to wait and acquire that message before decrementing, and that release-acquire would communicate the increment to Thread A. However reading into it further, even a relaxed fetch_sub is guaranteed to return unique values when two threads do it on the same variable at the same time, so I'm not sure that acquiring to synchronise with previous decrements is necessary either because if N threads are doing a relaxed decrement of a variable set to N, surely one of them has to observe the transition to 0?
Another reason I thought of might be because we would want to avoid reads which happen after the decrement to avoid moving behind the decrement, but I'm also uncertain about that because surely any of those reads would have to be known to be to be to an address not being deallocated if the branch is taken, otherwise the program would still be wrong in a single threaded context (accesses which would be incorrect if the branch would be taken would happening before the branch, which obviously can happen in hardware but would be invalidated by the branch misprediction)
I get that a release is necessary to make sure that when the memory is deallocated the changes to the data from the current thread are visible to the deallocating thread (since the changes may effect the behaviour of the destructor) and that an acquire is necessary on the deallocating thread to receive those changes, but I can't think of a reason why the acquire is necessary on the path where the memory isn't deallocated.
Is moving the acquire to a fence only on the branch where the memory is deallocated still correct and combining the acquire and release into the increment just an arbitrary choice that everyone made? Or is there some aspect of the memory model I've misunderstood that makes the acquire necessary before the decrement? Or perhaps there's something about having the acquire be on a fence instead of an instruction that makes it either incorrect or has too much of a performance penalty when the branch is taken, although I don't think the differences between an instruction acquire vs a fence acquire (which I know are slightly different) are that harsh

If your reference counted object (the object itself, or its reference count) is guaranteed to only be accessed and modified by a single thread, then no special release/acquire operations are needed.    If your reference counted object is shared between multiple threads (most importantly, modified by one thread concurrently with being accessed/modified by another thread) without sequencing, then the behaviour is undefined, and some scheme (e.g. release/acquire operations) is required to avoid that undefined behaviour.

The question isn't about the object, it's about the ordering around the reference count increment/decrement. Assume the object consists of an array whose elements are all guaranteed to only be operated on by one thread.

My implementation of release function, that we used throughout our code base, is like your second version: fetch_sub with memory_order_acq_rel, then std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire) when reaching 0 before deleting. It seems perfectly stable like that. Except that I use memory_order_acq_relwhen building for ThreadSanitizer, because it doesn't support atomic_thread_fence.

How's your weak_ptr::lock implemented? You have to make sure it doesn't resurrect an undead object. It is a legitimate case of trying to increment the count, while the object is about to be destructed in another thread due to count of 1. The increment in lock must be perfectly synchronized with the decrement in release function.

@Red.Wave The first example I'm using is an abridged version of the libc++ implementation of std::shared_ptr. That uses separate reference counts for weak and shared owners.

Your “series of events” corresponds to thread B trying to copy a shared_ptr as A is destroying it, which is undefined behavior.  There has to be a happens-before from that copy to the destruction, which is how B’s increment (even relaxed) becomes known.

@Ifier I guess you have not dug into weak_ptr yet. The weak_ptr::lock function is a specific case that increases both counts. If the shared count is increased after the deletion of object, a memory bug will be introduced. The implementation must guarantee that such bug is not possible.

@DavisHerring Ah OK, I see, in order to avoid a situation where B might be incrementing the refcount from 0, A would have to delay it's destruction until it received some sort of message which indicated that B had completed it's copy, which would have to be a release-acquire relationship, and therefore communicate the increment to A. I'm not sure that the question in full is answered though because the fetch_sub would (I think) still have to observe a value of either 2 or 1 depending on if B has decremented after the message or not, so the acquire still seems unnessecary.

This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72661110/why-doesnt-the-libc-shared-ptr-implementation-split-acq-rel-fetch-sub-into-re which does not have an accepted answer, but it seems that everyone agrees that the implementation with the conditional fence is still correct.
